# Transmit File After Redirecting to a new Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-2

In my project, I got a page that creates guest users for a number of products chosen.
Basically you tell the application how many users to create for each product you choose.

When you click 'Save' I generate the guests, save their username + password (before encryption) in a csv file that I transmit at the end of the process, and finally redirect the user to the index page.

The problem happens at the file transmission and the consequent redirection to a new action:

```
Private Sub DownloadCsv(ByVal csv As List(Of String), ByVal filename As String)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    For Each Str As String In csv
        sb.AppendLine(Str)
    Next
    ' Clear any previous response
    Response.Clear()


    ' Indicate we're returning a CSV file
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv"

    ' Provide filename for download            
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & filename & ".csv")            

    ' Write actual CSV data
    Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString()))


End Sub
```

And in my action, I call this method DownloadCsv and then I redirect to the Index like so:

```
Return (RedirectToAction("GroupIndex"))
```

What's happening is the page transmitting the file to the browser and never doing the redirect that follows.
I read a bit on the matter and found out that once you add an Header to our Response object and Write a file, it will automatically close the Response. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

How can I make it possible to transmit this file after the user has being redirected to the Index or Redirect to the Index after he either saves or cancels the file download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have crossed this problem before and it's not easy to solve, at least not in a cross-browser way. On the `onclick` of your Save button, you can set a Javascript timeout which, in a couple of seconds, does a client-side redirect using `window.location = "...url...";`. However, I'm pretty sure that didn't work on one particular browser (IE probably).

Otherwise, I would rethink your workflow to avoid having a download and redirect in the same action. Provide a "Save" button, followed by a "Back to Index" button, for example. In my case, I put my download action in a jQuery overlay "dialog". When the file had started downloading, it was just a case of closing the dialog.